# Is there a module for searching in msword doc-files on linux?

Tags: linux, perl, search, ms-word

Usually I'm searching with `grep -r --color word /path/dir` but this doesn't work good with binary files. So I would like to write a Perl-script that does something similar. Therefore I am searching a module which can read doc-files on a Linux-machine (maybe something analogous to Spreadsheet::ParseExcel for ms-word-documents).

Comment: What are your requirements, exactly? Remember, .doc files and the newer .docx files are very different file formats. So even if you found a Perl module that can parse .doc files it might not support .docx files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of word to text converters (like antidoc, wv, catdoc, unoconv ...). You can grep through their output. This is also what msysgit does for cataloging doc files.

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to sound snarky, this is the danger of working with closed source proprietary documents. You might be stuck using the tools provided by the developer.

To your actual question, there are a few things you can do:

1. Open the file and save as RTF (rich text) or even as plain text, this should be more searchable.
2. Open with LibreOffice (called OpenOffice before the Oracle takeover forced a fork) which might allow more customizable searching (if someone has provided such a plugin) or which could be used to convert via method 1